How to verify and process a Shopify webhook in Node.js on AWS Lambda with API Gateway?
I am a Shopify store owner. In the admin of my store, in Settings > Notifications > Webhooks, I've created a webhook for "order creation" and provided my endpoint URL. Shopify provides a string/token the webhooks will be signed with (presumably for me to use in my code). I am not using webhooks in the context of a Shopify app. This is a simple URL endpoint.
My endpoint URL is a AWS API Gateway for a Lambda function using Node.js. I am currently using a Lambda proxy integration in order to access the entire HTTP request as-is (via a catch-all ANY method), although I'm not sure if this is necessary or working.
I am using the Shopify Node.js library and calling the shopify.webhooks.validate method, which accepts 3 parameters:

rawBody: The raw body of the request received by the app.
rawRequest: The HTTP Request object used by your runtime.
rawResponse: The HTTP Response object used by your runtime. Required for Node.js.

I am assuming this method computes the HMAC digest and compares it to the header value so I do not have to write this code myself.
Questions:
How do I access the raw HTTP Request object and HTTP Response object in this Node.js Lambda environment? In Express it would be req and res. But I am not using Express.
Also, where do I use the webhooks signing string/token Shopify generates for me? Do I use that as the ACCESS_TOKEN? Or do I install the Shopify Headless app and use the private access token under Storefront API?
Node.js code (index.js):
import "@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node";
import { shopifyApi } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

const SHOP_NAME = 'store_shop_name';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'store_access_token';

const shopify = shopifyApi({
    shopName: SHOP_NAME,
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const {isValid, topic, domain} = await shopify.webhooks.validate({
        rawBody: ?? // request body as string
        rawRequest: ?? // http request object
        rawResponse: ?? // http response object
    });

    if (!isValid) {
        return {
            statusCode: 400
        };
    }
    
    // process here
}

Any relevant examples would be greatly appreciated.

In Lambda you don't get access to the response directly, as you would in a Node.js environment, but you can access the body and headers from the request.
You could try something like this:
import "@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node";
import { shopifyApi } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

// Shopify store credentials
const SHOP_NAME = "store_shop_name";
const ACCESS_TOKEN = "store_access_token";
const WEBHOOK_SECRET = "webhook_secret"; // This is the signing secret/token provided by Shopify

const shopify = shopifyApi({
  shopName: SHOP_NAME,
  accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
  apiSecretKey: WEBHOOK_SECRET, // Pass the webhook secret here for validation
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let rawBody = event.body;

  try {
    // If rawBody does not work, try parsing the body data:
    // body = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const { isValid, topic, domain } = await shopify.webhooks.validate({
      rawBody: rawBody,
      rawRequest: { headers: headers }, // Pass the headers in place of the full request object
      rawResponse: {}, // Lambda doesn't provide a response object, so you can pass an empty object
    });

    if (!isValid) {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: "Invalid webhook signature",
      };
    }

    // Process the webhook data
    const payload = JSON.parse(rawBody);

    // Example: handle an order creation event
    if (topic === "orders/create") {
      console.log("Order created:", payload);
      // Your logic to handle the order creation
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Webhook processed successfully",
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    const response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: {
        message: err.message || "Server error",
      },
    };
    return response;
  }
};

